# How do I parse only value in json file

Tags: c#, json, json.net

From this code. I want to parse only value from the json file

```
 if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {                    
                using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.Value != null)
                        {
                            richTextBox1.Text = reader.Value.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error while parsing json file. Please try again.");

                        }
                    }


                }

            }
```

And the value is

```
 {
"install.and": "a",
"install.emailAddress": "E-mailová adresa",
"install.emailIncorrect": "Zadejte platnou e-mailovou adresu.",
"install.emailRetryPrefix": "Neobdrželi jste e-mail? Zkuste to znovu",
"install.emailRetry": "Zkuste to znovu",
"install.emailSend": "Odeslat odkaz",
"install.emailSent": "E-mail byl odeslán!",
"install.emailSentTo": "E-mail byl odeslán",
"install.emailText1": "Můžete navštívit",
"install.emailText2": "Pokud nám poskytnete e-mailovou adresu, budeme vám moci poslat odkaz na pozdější instalaci.",
"install.installing": "Instalace...",
"install.later": "Instalovat později",
"install.licenseAgreement": "licenční smlouva",
"install.privacyPolicy": "zásady ochrany osobních údajů",
"install.quit": "Ukončit instalační program"
}
```

I want to parse it after : symbol. (Is it value?) to show in richTextbox as Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
{
    var o = JObject.Load(reader);
    foreach (var v in o)
    {
        var value = v.Value.Value<string>();
        //do whatever you want with value
    }
}
```

If you want only values joined by newline, then try this one

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
{
    var o = JObject.Load(reader);
    var e = o.Values().Select(x => x.Value<string>());
    var values = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e);

    //do whatever you want with values
}
```

Comment: That's very useful~~ Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Introduce two temporary variable to hold key and value

```
   string key = string.Empty;
   string value = string.Empty;
```

Modify your while loop like this,

```
 using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.Value != null)
                    {
                        key = reader.Value.ToString();
                        if (reader.Read())
                            value = reader.Value.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", key,value);
                        //Instead of writing in a console, process and write it in Rich text box.
                    }                        
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.Net and create a model :

```
public class JsonObject
{
    [JsonProperty("install.and")]
    public string install_and { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.emailAddress")]
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.emailIncorrect")]
    public string emailIncorrect { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("emailRetryPrefix")]
    public string emailRetryPrefix { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.emailRetry")]
    public string emailRetry { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.emailSend")]
    public string emailSend { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.emailSent")]
    public string emailSent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.emailSentTo")]
    public string emailSentTo { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.emailText1")]
    public string emailText1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.emailText2")]
    public string emailText2 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.installing")]
    public string installing { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.later")]
    public string later { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.licenseAgreement")]
    public string licenseAgreement { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.privacyPolicy")]
    public string privacyPolicy { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("install.quit")]
    public string quit { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can prase you json file:

```
string json_data = "{\"install.and\": \"a\",\"install.emailAddress\": \"E-mailová adresa\",\"install.emailIncorrect\": \"Zadejte platnou e-mailovou adresu.\",\"install.emailRetryPrefix\": \"Neobdrželi jste e-mail? Zkuste to znovu\",\"install.emailRetry\": \"Zkuste to znovu\",\"install.emailSend\": \"Odeslat odkaz\",\"install.emailSent\": \"E-mail byl odeslán!\",\"install.emailSentTo\": \"E-mail byl odeslán\",\"install.emailText1\": \"Můžete navštívit\",\"install.emailText2\": \"Pokud nám poskytnete e-mailovou adresu, budeme vám moci poslat odkaz na pozdější instalaci.\",\"install.installing\": \"Instalace...\",\"install.later\": \"Instalovat později\",\"install.licenseAgreement\": \"licenční smlouva\",\"install.privacyPolicy\": \"zásady ochrany osobních údajů\",\"install.quit\": \"Ukončit instalační program\"";

JsonObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObject>(json_data);
 richTextBox1.Text = data.emailAddress;
 richTextBox2.Text = data.emailIncorrect;
 richTextBox3.Text = data.emailRetry;
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Install newtonsoft.json from nuget package manager. Add the namespace

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

create a class to easily handle the values.

```
class Details
{
    public string and;
    public string EmailAddress;
    public string EmailIncorrect;
    public string EmailRetry;
    public string EmailSend;
    public string EmailSent;

}
```

Then read the file into a string and parse it using JObject.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string file = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            JObject jo = JObject.Parse(file);
            Details dt = new Details();
            dt.and = (string)jo["install.and"];
            richTextBox1.Text = reader.Value.ToString();
        }
```